# Firebase deploy without login

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

I'm trying deploy my firebase app. But when I try run 'firebase deploy', I got: [image]

Is any way to deploy the app automatically ( without human login to dashboard) ? I care only to send on firebase security rules.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `firebase login:ci` to work with continuous integration systems.

The command `firebase login:ci` will create a token, then you can use this token for deploying with:

```
firebase deploy --token
```

**[See the Github repo section on CI Systems for more information.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools#using-with-ci-systems)**